# How to switch mobile to desktop screen on Mobile view and desktop to mobile screen on actual view website with just one click?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I want to add button on mobile screen website so that while clicking on that button the actual view of website will open on the mobile screen and the vice-versa.

Please help me out.
Thankyou

Comment: yes from this url http://filzhut.net/projects/responsive-switch/

Answer (score 0):

you can use query string for this and then check and switch b/w screens like this

```
www.example.com?mode=mobile
```

or

```
www.example.com?mode=desktop
```

then

```
if(isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode']=='mobile')
{
  // perform action for mobile view
}
if(isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode']=='desktop')
{
  // perform action for desktop view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Viewport Meta Tag** defines how the layout will be shown on mobile.

you probably have something like this in head tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">`

Now suppose you have an anchor tag like this: `<a href="#" id="switch_layout">Switch layout</a>`

Then you can use the following script to switch between layouts on mobile.

```
$("#switch_layout").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass('desktop')){
        $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'initial-scale=1');
        $(this).toggleClass('desktop');
    }else{
        $('meta[name="viewport"]').attr('content', 'initial-scale=0');
        $(this).toggleClass('desktop');
    }
});
```

**Note:** This will only work on mobile & not on desktop.

**Code Explanation:**

- We start by listening for a click event on anchor tag with id switch_layout.
- to stop Anchor default functionality which is to go top of the page due to href="#" i used e.preventDefault().
- I am using desktop class to turn mobile layout on and off although this can also be done by a variable but applying class means css can take the advantage of it.

Comment: **P.S** If you have or can put the responsive css in different file then we can even switch layout on desktop.

Comment: here "e" takes value from where and what is the use of desktop class n how its peform.
Sorry but i think this information is uncomplete.Please help me while providing html n css related to this uper code
Thankyou

Comment: I have added explanation.